# How to render the item horizontally (Masonry Layout )?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, tailwind-css, masonry

I would like to render the items horizontally while the page load, refer to following images

```
<section
        tabindex="-1"
        class="relative mx-8 mt-10 mb-20 max-w-7xl focus:outline-none sm:mx-16 md:mx-20 lg:mx-24 xl:mx-auto"
    >
        <ul
            class="h-full w-full list-none columns-1 gap-4 space-y-12 overflow-hidden pb-32 md:columns-2 lg:columns-3 lg:gap-8 xl:columns-4"
        >
            <ExploreCard
                v-for="(post, index) in posts.data"
                :key="index"
                :post="post"
                :canLike="this.canLike"
            />
        </ul>       
</section>
```

**`Currently`**

[image]

**`Expected`**

[image]

Something like this,
https://reactjsexample.com/rendering-columns-from-a-list-of-children-with-horizontal-ordering/

> I am looking for a Js, Vue, or  CSS solution.

Comment: Share the reproducible example and complete code with what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with a package solution and it works perfectly fine!

[DaPotatoMan/vue-next-masonry](https://github.com/DaPotatoMan/vue-next-masonry)

**and this is how it looks like**

```
<masonry
            :cols="{ default: 4, 1024: 3, 768: 2, 640: 1 }"
            :gutter="{ default: 40, 1024: 30, 768: 20 }"
        >
            <div v-for="(post, index) in posts.data" :key="index" class="mb-10">
                <ExploreCard
                    v-for="(post, index) in posts.data"
                    :key="index"
                    :post="post"
                    :canLike="this.canLike"
                />
            </div>
</masonry>
```

In this way, all the post is rendered in horizontal order !

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you use tailwind class utility of grid to create a grid container:
[https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#:~:text=Use%20grid%20to%20create%20a%20grid%20container](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#:%7E:text=Use%20grid%20to%20create%20a%20grid%20container).

[image]

Comment: can you explain in more detail with codes?

Comment: @Lee Taylor,  but every post has different height ?

Comment: @ChaiFuuWong I didn't post the answer. I just improved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer with **pure CSS** from @haltersweb

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063940/17737657

[CSS-only masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout)

**display: inline-block**

```
ul {
    margin-left: .25em;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

**display: flex**

```
ul {
    margin-left: .25em;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 33.3%;
}

<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```

[image]